# @react-three/fiber: How do I create a helper for a shadow camera?

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

So i'm used to setting helpers like this:

```
useHelper(sLightRef, THREE.SpotLightHelper);

return <spotLight
        castShadow
        ref={sLightRef}
        position={[0, 2, 2]}
        args={["#fff", 0.4, 10, Math.PI * 0.3]}
        ></spotLight>
```

Which will create a helper on the SpotLight object.

What I don't understand is how to create one on the SpotLight's shadow camera. (spotlight.shadow.camera) We can't assign a ref() to it, since it's not in my return statement. It's created inside of SpotLight component.

In normal Three.js, this is easy:

```
const helper = new THREE.CameraHelper(spotlight.shadow.camera);
scene.add(helper);
```

How would I go about doing this in react-three-fiber? Is there something obvious i'm missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I played around with it a bit but I Couldn't find a clean solution. That's why I made my own hook that's built similarly to the useHelper hook.

```
// Components==============
import { useFrame, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber';
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { CameraHelper, Light } from 'three';
// =========================

export default function useShadowHelper(
  ref: React.MutableRefObject<Light | undefined>
) {
  const helper = useRef<CameraHelper>();
  const scene = useThree((state) => state.scene);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref.current) return;

    helper.current = new CameraHelper(ref.current?.shadow.camera);
    if (helper.current) {
      scene.add(helper.current);
    }

    return () => {
      if (helper.current) {
        scene.remove(helper.current);
      }
    };
  }, [helper.current?.uuid, ref.current]);

  useFrame(() => {
    if (helper.current?.update) {
      helper.current.update();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by [attaching](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/objects#attach) your own perspective camera to the spotlight.

```
useHelper(sLightRef, THREE.SpotLightHelper);
useHelper(shadowCameraRef, THREE.CameraHelper);

return <spotLight
        castShadow
        ref={sLightRef}
        position={[0, 2, 2]}
        args={["#fff", 0.4, 10, Math.PI * 0.3]}
       >
         <perspectiveCamera ref={shadowCameraRef} attach="shadow-camera" />
       </spotLight>
```